# Python: Help to create a loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have to do this function in a loop.

I would like to pass x. x, which indicates how many times the loop should go through.

It's about my data getting longer and longer:

```
def get_data(x):
ts = round(time.time())
url = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:'
timeframe = '1h:'
symbol = 'tBTCUSD'
period = 120 * 3600  # max. 120
start = '/hist?start=' + str((ts - period) * 1000)

end = '&end=' + str(ts * 1000)
string = url + timeframe + symbol + start + end

response = requests.get(string)
data = response.json()

time.sleep(1)

period2 = x * period
start = '/hist?start=' + str((ts - period2 - 3600) * 1000)
end = '&end=' + str((ts - period - 3600) * 1000)
string = url + timeframe + symbol + start + end

response = requests.get(string)
data1 = response.json()

data.extend(data1)
time.sleep(1)

return data
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: What's the issue? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you indent your code properly? Use four spaces. I can't figure out where the function boundaries are to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=0
While x < desired_number_of_loops: 
    do stuff
    x+=1
```

More about while loops [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp)